# Why is one of my my JEST mocks not working when the other works fine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have defined 2 JEST mocks. The problem I am getting. The first mock doesn't work but the second does.

```
import Helper from '../../test-helper'

import Storage from '@/storage'
import GuestContext from '@/auth/guest-context'
import UserContext from '@/auth/user-context'

// import LocalStorageGateway from '@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway'
const mockContextUpsert = jest.fn()

jest.mock('@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((authContext) => {
        return {
            authContext,
            context: {
                upsert: mockContextUpsert
            }
        }
    })
})

// import RemoteStorageGateway from '@/storage/remote/remote-storage-gateway'
const mockFetch = jest.fn()

jest.mock('@/storage/remote/remote-storage-gateway', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((authContext) => {
        return {
            authContext,
            fetch: mockFetch
        }
    })
})
```

I have tried...

- Commenting out the second mock definition
- Switching the orders
- Using `mockFetch` in the first mock instead of `mockContentUpsert` (after of course moving the definition of `mockFetch` up).
- Making the first mock a complete replica of the second with only the '@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway' line being changed.

The error I am getting is...

> ReferenceError: mockContextUpsert is not defined

I cannot understand why the first mock doesn't work when the second mock works perfectly.

This will also work, adding the mock variables to the second declaration (not of any use as they're different classes but for reference)...

```
const mockContextUpsert = jest.fn()
const mockFetch = jest.fn()

jest.mock('@/storage/remote/remote-storage-gateway', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((authContext) => {
        return {
            authContext: authContext,
            fetch: mockFetch,
            context: {
                upsert: mockContextUpsert
            }
        }
    })
})
```

The classes being mocked here are almost identical.

**UPDATE**

Removing the reference to `GuestContext()` [this is additional complication, has since been removed, and is confusing the actual problem the question is trying to ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this eventually - The issue here wasn't with the mocks themselves but the class being mocked.

The `LocalStorageGateway` class is used to create a private instance within an imported module `Storage`, as follows...

`const guestLocal = new LocalStorageGateway(new GuestContext())`

This static context is causing the mocked constructor to execute before the variables are defined as `Storage` is one of the first module imported.

There are several ways around this...

You can change this...

```
import Helper from '../../test-helper'

import Storage from '@/storage'
import GuestContext from '@/auth/guest-context'
import UserContext from '@/auth/user-context'

(insert mocks here)
```

to...

```
const mockContextUpsert = jest.fn()

import Helper from '../../test-helper'

import Storage from '@/storage'
import GuestContext from '@/auth/guest-context'
import UserContext from '@/auth/user-context'
```

for example (yuk?).

Alternatively you can wrap `mockContextUpsert` up in a wrapping function (my earlier not-really-good-enough answer) -> This feels a bit tidier to me.

```
const mockContextUpsert = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((authContext) => {
        return {
            authContext: authContext,
            context: {
                upsert: (cxt) => {
                    mockContextUpsert(cxt)
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I could also make `guestLocal` a function but I don't really want to do that and create new gateway instances every time I want to use it (It's why it's there in the first place). If `Storage` was a class it would be instantiated in the constructor but it isn't and has no real need to be.

Thanks to @Teneff for his input on this, his answer got my brain looking at it the right way around. **the variables are not hoisted** was key - They work differently - I was operating on an incorrect understanding that anything called `mockXXXX` would be hoisted up above the mock calls but they aren't they are just 'allowed'.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#using-with-es-module-imports):

> Jest will automatically hoist jest.mock calls to the top of the module (before any imports)

meaning that whenever you try to define the function being returned by the mock `mockGuestContext` is not yet defined

What you can do is create an auto-mock

```
import localStorageGateway from '@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway';
jest.mock('@/storage/local/local-storage-gateway');

// and since localStorageGateway is a function 
// jest will automatically create jest.fn() for it
// so you will be able to create authContext
const authContext = new GuestContext();

// and use it within the return value
localStorageGateway.mockReturnValue({
  authContext,
  context: {
    upsert: jest.fn(),
  }
})
```

Comment: This is true, but any variables named 'mockSomethingOrOther' are also hoisted. If you try to use a differently named variable you get a different and much more helpful error. The automock here doesn't serve my requirement as I need to change the behaviour of upsert for different tests. mockImplementation is needed over mockReturnValue as the mock is a class. Notice how I switched to pass the authContext into the constructor - that prevents GuestContext being undefined but doesn't fix inexplicable undefined errors on the other mockXXX variables unless I function wrap them.

Comment: @KeithJackson no, the variables are not hoisted if you change `jest.mock` to [jest.doMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) you'll see

Comment: According to the JEST documentation in order to use a variable you need to prepend the name with 'mock' so that it gets recognised in the hoisted mocks.

I'm aware that `GuestContext` would not be defined but, as you can see in my explanation above removing that made no difference. The issue affected all of the `mockXXX` variables.

I shall update to explain

Comment: Is this perhaps related to when the INSTANCE of the mock is created? Both of the mocks above are constructor Mocks for ES6 classes, so `mockContextUpsert` shouldn't be required until a new instance is created. Perhaps the second mock is created later...